# More efficient way to delete list item with index Python

Tags: python, list, indexing, del

More efficient way to delete list item with index Python

What is a more efficient alternative to:

```
    del List[List.index(aString)]
```

Comment: homework..........................

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`list.remove`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) as below

```
x = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a']
x.remove('a')
print(x)
# ['b', 'c', 'a']

x.remove('d')
# ValueError
```

Note that if there is no 'd' in your list then it will throw a ValueError, you could get around this by using a [`try...except...`](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HandlingExceptions) block

```
try:
    x.remove('d')
except ValueError:
    pass
```

Answer (score 4):

I think you should try `pop()` too. You can remove the elements by specifying the index number as you have asked in your question.

```
aList = [123, 'xyz', 'zara', 'abc'];
print aList
print aList.pop(0)   ###pop(index_number)
print aList
```

output will be :

```
[123, 'xyz', 'zara', 'abc']
123
['xyz', 'zara', 'abc']
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to delete by index then use pop it will not raise error:

```
x_list = ['abx', 'sdf', 'sdk', '4', '45']
x_list.pop('sdf')
print x_list
['abx', 'sdf', '4', '45']
```

You can also do:

```
x_list = [x for x in x_list if x!='sdk']
print x_list
['abx', 'sdf', '4', '45']
```